# Guessing kubernetes limits for kubernetes deployments

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any  way we can correctly guess how much resource limits we need to keep for running deployments on kubernetes clusters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can guess that single threaded application most likely won't need more that 1 CPU.

For any other programs: no, there is not easy way to guess it. Every application is different, and reacts differently under different workloads.

The easiest way to figure out how many resources it needs is to run it and measure it.

Run some benchmarks/profilers and see how application behaves. Then make decisions based on that.